# Hide And Show elements of an unordered list on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to build a sidebar navigation in which I have the categories listed.
With which there is a button which expands the subcategories of the particular category on clicking.
I am failing to do so. For this I am using jQuery. Here is my function

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$( '.side-nav ul' ).slightSubmenu({
    buttonActivateEvents : 'click',
    handlerButtonIn : function($submenuUl) {
        $submenuUl.show(200);
    },
    handlerForceClose : function($submenuUl) {
        $submenuUl.hide(200);
    },
    prependButtons              : true
});
$('.side-nav ul.expand').show();
$('.side-nav li').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('collapse expand');
});
$('.side-nav .selection-path > span').addClass('opened');
});
</script>
```

Here is what I am trying to [build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjpOt.png). On expansion [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0Ywb.png).
My question is, can it happen with css? If yes, then how?
If anyone has a reference for the same, then please provide me with the url of that website. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want make a collapsible tree with css can use a directory pattern design like this:

```css
*{margin:0;padding:0;}
body{padding:100px;background:#929292;font-size:100%;font-family:"Arial";}
input{font-size:1em;}
ol.tree{padding-left:30px;}
li{list-style-type:none;color:#fff;position:relative;margin-left:-15px;}
li label{padding-left:37px;cursor:pointer;background:url("https://www.thecssninja.com/demo/css_tree/folder-horizontal.png") no-repeat 15px 2px;display:block;}
li input{width:1em;height:1em;position:absolute;left:-0.5em;top:0;opacity:0;cursor:pointer;}
li input + ol{height:1em;margin:-16px 0 0 -44px;background:url("https://www.thecssninja.com/demo/css_tree/toggle-small-expand.png") no-repeat 40px 0;}
li input + ol > li{display:none;margin-left:-14px !important;padding-left:1px}
li.file{margin-left:-1px !important;}
li.file a{display:inline-block;padding-left:21px;color:#fff;text-decoration:none;background:url("https://www.thecssninja.com/demo/css_tree/document.png") no-repeat 0 0;}
li input:checked + ol{height:auto;margin:-21px 0 0 -44px;padding:25px 0 0 80px;background:url("https://www.thecssninja.com/demo/css_tree/toggle-small.png") no-repeat 40px 5px;}
li input:checked + ol > li{display:block;margin:0 0 0.063em;}
li input:checked + ol > li:first-child{margin:0 0 0.125em;}
```

```html
<ol class="tree">
  <li>
    <label for="menu-1">menu-1</label>
    <input type="checkbox" checked id="menu-1" />
    <ol>
      <li>
        <label for="menu-1-1">menu-1-1</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="menu-1-1" />
        <ol>
          <li>
            <label for="menu-1-1-1">menu-1-1-1</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="menu-1-1-1" />
            <ol>
              <li>
                <label for="menu-1-1-1-1">menu-1-1-1-1</label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="menu-1-1-1-1" />
                <ol>
                  <li class="file"><a href="">menu-1-1-1-1-1</a></li>
                  <li class="file"><a href="">menu-1-1-1-1-2</a></li>
                  <li class="file"><a href="">menu-1-1-1-1-3</a></li>
                </ol>
              </li>
              <li class="file"><a href="">menu-1-1-1-2</a></li>
              <li class="file"><a href="">menu-1-1-1-3</a></li>
              <li class="file"><a href="">menu-1-1-1-4</a></li>
              <li class="file"><a href="">menu-1-1-1-5</a></li>
              <li class="file"><a href="">menu-1-1-1-6</a></li>
            </ol>
          </li>
          <li class="file"><a href="">menu-1-1-2</a></li>
          <li class="file"><a href="">menu-1-1-3</a></li>
          <li class="file"><a href="">menu-1-1-4</a></li>
        </ol> 
      </li>
      <li class="file"><a href="">menu-1-2</a></li>
      <li class="file"><a href="">menu-1-3</a></li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  
  <li>
    <label for="menu-2">menu-2</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="menu-2" />
    <ol>
      <li>
        <label for="menu-2-1">menu-2-1</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="menu-2-1" />
        <ol>
          <li>
            <label for="menu-2-1-1">menu-2-1-1</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="menu-2-1-1" />
            <ol>
              <li class="file"><a href="">menu-2-1-1-1</a></li>
              <li class="file"><a href="">menu-2-1-1-2</a></li>
              <li class="file"><a href="">menu-2-1-1-3</a></li>
              <li class="file"><a href="">menu-2-1-1-4</a></li>
              <li class="file"><a href="">menu-2-1-1-5</a></li>
            </ol>
          </li>
          <li class="file"><a href="">menu-2-1-2</a></li>
          <li class="file"><a href="">menu-2-1-3</a></li>
          <li class="file"><a href="">menu-2-1-4</a></li>
        </ol> 
      </li>
      <li class="file"><a href="">menu-2-2</a></li>
      <li class="file"><a href="">menu-2-3</a></li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  
  <li>
    <label for="menu-3">menu-3</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="menu-3" />
    <ol>
      <li>
        <label for="menu-3-1">menu-3-1</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="menu-3-1" />
        <ol>
          <li>
            <label for="menu-3-1-1">menu-3-1-1</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="menu-3-1-1" />
            <ol>
              <li class="file"><a href="">menu-3-1-1-1</a></li>
              <li class="file"><a href="">menu-3-1-1-2</a></li>
              <li class="file"><a href="">menu-3-1-1-3</a></li>
              <li class="file"><a href="">menu-3-1-1-4</a></li>
              <li class="file"><a href="">menu-3-1-1-5</a></li>
            </ol>
          </li>
          <li class="file"><a href="">menu-3-1-2</a></li>
          <li class="file"><a href="">menu-3-1-3</a></li>
          <li class="file"><a href="">menu-3-1-4</a></li>
        </ol> 
      </li>
      <li class="file"><a href="">menu-3-2</a></li>
      <li class="file"><a href="">menu-3-3</a></li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  
  <li>
    <label for="menu-4">menu-4</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="menu-4" />
    <ol>
      <li>
        <label for="menu-4-1">menu-4-1</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="menu-4-1" />
        <ol>
          <li>
            <label for="menu-4-1-1">menu-4-1-1</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="menu-4-1-1" />
            <ol>
              <li class="file"><a href="">menu-4-1-1-1</a></li>
              <li class="file"><a href="">menu-4-1-1-2</a></li>
              <li class="file"><a href="">menu-4-1-1-3</a></li>
              <li class="file"><a href="">menu-4-1-1-4</a></li>
              <li class="file"><a href="">menu-4-1-1-5</a></li>
            </ol>
          </li>
          <li class="file"><a href="">menu-4-1-2</a></li>
          <li class="file"><a href="">menu-4-1-3</a></li>
          <li class="file"><a href="">menu-4-1-4</a></li>
        </ol> 
      </li>
      <li class="file"><a href="">menu-4-2</a></li>
      <li class="file"><a href="">menu-4-3</a></li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  
  <li>
    <label for="menu-5">menu-5</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="menu-5" />
    <ol>
      <li>
        <label for="menu-5-1">menu-5-1</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="menu-5-1" />
        <ol>
          <li>
            <label for="menu-5-1-1">menu-5-1-1</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="menu-5-1-1" />
            <ol>
              <li class="file"><a href="">menu-5-1-1-1</a></li>
              <li class="file"><a href="">menu-5-1-1-2</a></li>
              <li class="file"><a href="">menu-5-1-1-3</a></li>
              <li class="file"><a href="">menu-5-1-1-4</a></li>
              <li class="file"><a href="">menu-5-1-1-5</a></li>
            </ol>
          </li>
          <li class="file"><a href="">menu-5-1-2</a></li>
          <li class="file"><a href="">menu-5-1-3</a></li>
          <li class="file"><a href="">menu-5-1-4</a></li>
        </ol> 
      </li>
      <li class="file"><a href="">menu-5-2</a></li>
      <li class="file"><a href="">menu-5-3</a></li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  
</ol>
```

The rest of the work is aplly your style design. I hope you find it useful

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna use a UI framework for that (and building most of your UI), you will save a lot of time and make sure it's cross-browser compatible and stable. jQuery is IMHO nowadays a low-level manipulation, why do something it has been done and tested already? I use it only for custom, specific cases.

Bootstrap is really popular and comes in components you can get only what you need out of it. Collapse is the component you need.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the snippet. Hope it is helpful to you.

```js
$("#btnID").click(function(){
  $("#myTabs").slideToggle(),
  $(this).toggleClass("active"),

  
    $("#myTabs li a").on("click",function(){
      $("#myTabs").slideUp()
       $('#btnID').removeClass("active")
    });
    
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="sub-nav"><button class="btn text-uppercase" id="btnID"><span>Alle websites</span></button>
             <ul id="myTabs" class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" style="display: none;">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#" role="unieke-tab" >EINZIGARTIGE WEBSEITEN</a></li>   
                    <li class=""><a href="#">WEBSHOPS</a></li>
                                   
                </ul>
                </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to achieve this is with only CSS, taking advantage of the sibling selector (`~`) and hidden radio elements!

```css
a {
  color: #223;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.sub-menu {
  display: block;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height 0.3s;
  overflow: hidden;
  will-change: max-height;
}

input:checked ~ .sub-menu {
  max-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
Side menu:
<ul>
  <li>
    <label for="parent1">Parent link 1</label>
    <input type="radio" id="parent1" hidden name="sub-menu-trigger">

    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Sub item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub item 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub item 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  
  <li>
    <label for="parent2">Parent link 2</label>
    <input type="radio" id="parent2" hidden name="sub-menu-trigger">
    
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Sub item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub item 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub item 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub item 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub item 5</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>  
</ul>
```